# Can I transition a 12 mm to a 8 mm laminate wood floor in an adjacent room?

Tags: flooring, laminate

Is there a way to transition a 12 mm laminate floor to a 8 mm laminate floor in an adjacent room?  We have had trouble finding the same color flooring to replace the floor in an adjacent room except for one in an 8 mm size.  Would a reducer 1/2 in. Thick x 1-3/4 in. Wide x 72 in. Length work?  Any suggestions?

Comment: Pictures are so handy with problems like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use a T transition as picture below, there is nothing you need to do.  They make T transitions like the one pictured to meet floors of varying heights.   You just play with the strip you get until you are happy.

[image]

If you want a cleaner transition then you pull up the subfloor top layer, then you build up the subfloor so it slowly goes up to the desired level, and then flatten that level out the last 12" or so.   My go-to on this is asphalt roofing shingle.   They layer up perfectly for slopes and they lay flat right away - with some other things you worry that you will flatten them out too much after screwing subfloor back in.

Answer (score 0):

4 mm is between 1/4" and 1/8". With a transition I doubt it would be very noticeable. You can add 1/4" (6.35 mm) underlayment under the new laminate and that would reduce the difference to 2.35 mm which is between 1/8" and 1/16". Of course the new laminate would now be the higher one, but the difference in height would be reduce in half